# Vulkan Device Extension Loading

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am having *extra* hard time in getting Vulkan device extensions to work.  My environment is
Ubuntu 22 and I am using the latest Vulkan developer environment (version 1.3.268).  I'm playing
around with an NVidia GPU.

This is what I do:

- Create a vulkan instance
- Get a physical device
- Create (logical) device and for the logical device, request these extensions:

```
VK_KHR_video_queue
VK_KHR_video_decode_queue
VK_KHR_video_decode_h264
```

i.e. when I create the device, I do this:

```
...
VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceCreateInfo = {};
deviceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 3;
deviceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = // those extension names
...
```

Later in the program, I am calling the function `vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR` that is part of the `VK_KHR_video_queue` extension.

The program compiles ok, however, the linker says:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x21eb): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR'
```

I can fix that, if I load the function "manually" from the device:

```
#include ...
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main() {

    ...
    // create instance and logical device

    // define vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR
    PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR;

    // set value for vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR = 
        (PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR)
        vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR");

    VkResult result = vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR(
        pdevice, &vk_video_profile, &vk_video_cap);
    ...

}
```

But the problem is, that now the extension function `vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR` is only defined
in the context of the `main()` function.  For more general purpose situations, I'd like to have
`vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR` available in the global context
(i.e. callable from any function, without the need to always reload it).

So let's try this:

```
#include ...
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main() {

    ...
    // create instance and logical device

    // DO NOT REDEFINE vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR in the current local context
    // PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR;

    // set value for vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR = 
        (PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR)
        vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR");

    VkResult result = vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR(
        pdevice, &vk_video_profile, &vk_video_cap);
    ...

}
```

But when I do that, the compiler throws `error: assignment of function ...`.  That's because instead of a mere
pointer, `vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR` has been declared as a *function* in `vulkan_core.h`:

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR(
    VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, ...)
```

At this moment I am completely baffled: how can we load functions with `vkGetInstanceProcAdd` if that header file has defined them,
instead of pointers, as functions..  in the latter case the only way would be to have them in object files or in a library - but this is not the case:
the function's code (be it even just a "wrapper") is missing from the shared object library file:

```
nm -gD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so | grep -i "vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR"
```

gives nothing.

References:

- [vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR.html)
- [VK_KHR_video_queue](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_video_queue.html)
- [Vulkan Cookbook](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/game-development/9781786468154/1/ch01lvl1sec18/loading-device-level-functions)
- [About Vulkan Loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/main/docs/LoaderInterfaceArchitecture.md#architecture-of-the-vulkan-loader-interfaces-)

Comment: Hmm.. maybe the whole idea is to use/declare
"PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR;"
in a "local context", i.e. encapsulate it into a dedicated class/struct and just use it from there?

Comment: This is what may projects do. BTW why not use vulkan-hpp with dynamic dispatching? https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/tree/main#extensions--per-device-function-pointers

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess the idea of having defined the extension function *as a function* in the header file is, that if it *happens* to be in the corresponding `.so` library file, then all fine.

Otherwise one needs to load the function pointer "manually", as described above.  And if it's done "manually" then of course, it can't be in a "global scope", but it's inside some object class etc. as each vulkan instance needs to load the functions separately.

I like the following solution.  For each Vulkan instance, one can instantiate a `DeviceExtension` object.

```
DeviceExtension ex;
ex.fill(vk_instance);
ex.vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR(...)
etc.
```

DeviceExtension can also be a member of any other class (Say, `VulkanDecoder` class in this particular case).

Here is the code for class `DeviceExtension`:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#define LOADFUNC(name)             \
name = (PFN_##name)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(this->instance, #name);       \
if (name == nullptr) {                                           \
  std::cerr << "Could not load device-level Vulkan function named: " #name << std::endl; \
  this->ok=false; \
}

#define DEFUNC(name) \
PFN_##name name

class DeviceExtensions {
public:
    DeviceExtensions() : instance(nullptr), ok(false) {};
    ~DeviceExtensions() {};

public:
    void fill(VkInstance instance) {
        this->ok=true;
        this->instance=instance;
        LOADFUNC(vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR);
        // pile up here all extension functions
    }
    bool isOk() {
        return this->ok;
    }

private:
    bool ok;
    VkInstance instance;

public:
    DEFUNC(vkGetPhysicalDeviceVideoCapabilitiesKHR);
    // pile up here all extension functions
};
```

**EDIT:** as mentioned in the comments of the original question, "dynamic dispatching" might be another option